# How facebook select images for sharetool when og:image meta tag does not work?

Tags: html, facebook, meta-tags

First, I know how to solve the problem if the og:image meta tag is not set properly. having that said.  I need to know how they select the images that appear (like randomly selected from the site) when that meta tag is wrong used or is not used at all.

hope is not a random behavior  and have some explanation for how they do this. If you can provide some official explanation or documentation, I would appreciate so much.

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the meta tag og:image as described at http://ogp.me/

And if that tag doesn't exists we try to find a good image to use. We use image size and where on the page it is for figure out a good one. But we may get it wrong.

Comment: Hello @WizKid and thanks for the answer. Can you provide me some documentation about that process where you try to get good images using the size and position of the page images?

Comment: There is no documentation. And things changes. If you want to decide which image we show use og:image